# SQL - Delete the last row if there are more than x of the same value

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Can do something like this in sql:

`DELETE TOP 1 FROM items WHERE ItemID = 'xxx' and count(ItemID) > 6 order by index`

So if there are more than 6 rows with 'xxx' as the itemID, it deletes anything newer than those 6 with that item id?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think,we can't use **top 1** in delete query. But we can use this in where condition as sub query. Get the list of database ids using sub query and delete it.

```
DELETE FROM items WHERE id in (select top 1 id from items ItemID = 'xxx' and count(ItemID) > 6 order by index)
```